# Why can't I bind anything?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, expression-blend

[image]

For some reason, I can no longer bind anything through Expression Blend.  I have to go into the XAML and bind things there which is a real productivity kill. In the screenshot above, there is absolutely no reason why the OK should not be enabled and available to click. Is this a known bug? Am I doing something wrong? My XAML is checked out and not read only. If I manually bind the control and come back the bind dialog works fine. This happens everywhere with all kinds of binding.

I've also posted this on the Expression Blend forum [here](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/5df874a3-4045-42aa-b48f-0c9eaaf43a5a).

**Edits:**

I've recently plugged my project into TFS 2012.  It was in Source Safe before (yeah I know). The file is checked out and NOT set to read-only. But might this change have caused the problem? Anybody?

**Further Edits:**

This is getting really frustrating. A person on the Expression Blend forum told me that this has something I can do to get it to work. Its a real productivity sucker to have to switch over to XAML whenever I want to bind something. Its also not just element binding, its all binding that is like this. HELP!

Comment: Are there XAML errors in the Error pane of Blend?

Comment: Have you tried in visual studio to see if the bindings work there ?

Comment: There are no errors. The bindings work fine everywhere else. In fact, after I set them manually directly in the XAML, this dialog works. It just won't work on new bindings. This is getting really frustrating. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug that Microsoft is aware of. You can find more information;

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/blend/thread/3da0b61e-cf0a-48c7-9f6e-30c07dfe6ad7

and...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/he-IL/blend/thread/002b36d0-dffc-444d-81a2-4067797516a6

though I'm not sure if there's a submission to MSConnect for it even if Erik over at MSFT says it is "on his to-do list." Hope this helps...

Comment: So I guess this really is a bug?  Its odd though. There is not a lot of noise about it.

Comment: That's Blend 4 correct? If so they're scrapping support for it in lieu of Blend being packaged with VS in VS2012, I did see where someone said if you start the bind declaration (ie; type `{Binding }` in the xaml) then it will let you do it how you're used to. Yay M$ :D

Comment: That only works some times. Once in a while, after typing in the `{Binding}` manually, changes in the UI don't stick. I can't wait until I can up to VS2012. I'm not a designer after all. Thanks.